# Finding a different sort of connected component

Tags: algorithm

I would like to define a uni-connected component in a directed graph to be a subgraph where for each pair of nodes u and v there exists either a path from u to v or from v to u. It should also have the property that it isn't a subgraph of another uni-connected component.

I know how to find weakly and strongly connected components. How can you find uni-connected components?

A very inefficient method might do a breadth search from each node to see which nodes can be reached from it and try to compute the components somehow from these sets of nodes.

Comment: Is it your definition: "there exists either a path from u to v or from v to u" - but **not from both v to u and u to v** ???

Comment: I'd say this is a call for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fallen As the graph is directed I don't require that there is a path in both directions. There could be but it is not required.

Comment: Do you mean "for **every** pair of nodes _u_ and _v_ in the subgraph"? What's an example of a connected subgraph that _isn't_ "uniconnected"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell All uniconnected graphs will be weakly connected but may not be strongly connected. For example the simple graph with two nodes A -> B is uniconnected but not strongly connected. The graph A->B<-C is weakly connected but not unidirected.

Comment: But for `A->B<-C`, aren't both the connected subgraphs `A->B` and `C->B` uniconnected components?  A connected graph, sub- or not, has a path between any two of its nodes. Your list of uniconnected components is the list of connected subgraphs.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Are you referring to weakly or strongly connected subgraphs? For directed graphs these are the standard options I believe. Neither corresponds to my definition. The whole graph is weakly connected so that does not help. Maybe it would be clearer to ask you what algorithm you have in mind?

Comment: [You said above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765975/finding-a-different-sort-of-connected-component?noredirect=1#comment25909554_17765975) you don't care about strong connections, just weak.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  As you say A->B<-C has two maximal unidirected components but only one maximal weakly connected component. I hope that makes the difference clear.

Comment: How does this problem differ from finding a maximal connected component in an undirected graph with the same node set, and an edge between any pair of nodes that are connected in at least one direction in the original graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maximal uni-connected subgraph (I refuse to call them "components", because the underlying relation is not transitive) contains all or none of a strongly connected component. As a first step in enumerating maximal uni-connected subgraphs, then, collapse each SCC to a single vertex (i.e., compute the condensation of the input graph).

A uni-connected subgraph of an acyclic directed graph has the property that, for distinct nodes u and v, either there is a path from u to v, or a path from v to u, but not both. Write u < v if there is a path from u to v and u != v. Since either u < v or v < u but not both, and u < v and v < w implies u < w, the relation < is a strict total order. By sorting the vertices in the subgraph, we find that they lie on a single path. This path is maximal if and only if no vertex can be inserted, which means that it begins at a source (no incoming edges), ends at a sink (no outgoing edges), and is comprised solely of edges that appear in the [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of the acyclic directed graph.

Here is one algorithm for enumerating maximal uni-connected subgraphs of a directed graph G.

1. Find the strong components of G. Contract them, yielding the condensation G'.
2. Compute the transitive reduction G'' of G'.
3. Enumerate all source-sink paths by, e.g., depth-first search, then replace each node by its strong component in G.

Here is a graph family with exponentially many maximal uni-connected subgraphs. All edges are directed downward.

```
  *
 / \
*   *
 \ /
  *
 / \
*   *
 \ /
  *
 / \
  .
  .
  .
 \ /
  *
 / \
*   *
 \ /
  *
```

Comment: Thank you. So I understand, step 2 takes cubic time in practice? What is the worst case complexity of step 3?

Comment: @phoenix Exponential, but only since there can be exponentially many uni-connected subgraphs (see my edited answer for an example). Each one costs poly-time to output.

Comment: For any graph the minimum number of maximal uni connected subgraphs that cover every node is always linear though surely.  It would be helpful to be able to output such a minimal covering. That is what I had in mind. How much is poly time in your algorithm assuming cubic for step two?

Comment: @phoenix Yes, there are linear-size covers. In step 3, instead of finding all paths, find a minimum-size set of paths whose union contains all vertices, i.e., a [path cover](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10304235/2144669). The overall running time I think is dominated by the cubic-time transitive reduction. If the maximality of the uni-connected subgraphs is unimportant to you except in so far as to minimize the number of subgraphs used, then you can omit the transitive reduction, and the running time will be dominated by finding the cover (which looks like one invocation of Hopcroft--Karp).

Comment: That looks very nice. Thank you. Now if only someone would upvote your answer!

Comment: @phoenix Don't worry about it. I don't do this for the rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Construct an undirected graph G that has the same node set as the original graph, and an edge between each pair of nodes that are connected by an edge in either direction in the original graph.

Find the connected components of G by breadth first search. Loop through the nodes, but start a new search only at nodes that are not part of any previously found component. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithms)

The nodes of each of these components also form the nodes of a uni-connected component of the original directed graph.

=============================================================

I now understand that every node has to have an edge to edge to every other node in the subset of the undirected graph, so what is needed is a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) in G, rather than a connected subgraph of G. Unfortunately, the decision form of the problem is NP-complete, and the function form is NP-hard.

See [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29#Free_software_for_searching_maximum_clique) for some free options for finding the clique.

Comment: This gives the wrong answer sadly. Consider A->B<-C again. Your method gives one uniconnected subgraph where there should be two.

Comment: @phoenix. I see. I was confused by the connected subgraph idea. You are actually looking for a clique. The means your problem is NP-complete. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that is right. See the other answer which has a poly time solution.

Comment: @phoenix If I now understand your problem, maximum clique, a classic NP-complete problem based on undirected graphs, is reducible to your problem by constructing a directed graph which has an edge in an arbitrary direction for each undirected edge in the original graph. The maximum clique will contain the same nodes as one of your components.