# minimum number of lines connecting points

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

A set of points are given in a 2D space. The X co-ordinate of all points is unique.

These points have to be joined by lines whose slope is between -1 to +1. Now if two or more such lines join each other, it'll be counted as a single line if the overall line does not "turn around".

A line joining (0,0) (1,1) and (0,2) is "turned around" at (1,1).In such case line joining (0,0) & (1,1) and (1,1) & (0,2) are two separate lines and cannot be counted as one.

How can I determine global minimum number of such "overall" lines (or at-least approximate solution to it)? Is it some known algorithm ?

All the final number of "overall" lines need not touch or intersect each other.

For example if I have points {(1,1)(3,3)(5,5)} the answer is 1

If I have points {(1,1)(2,5)(3,3)(4,6)(5,1)} the answer is 2. One line joining (2,5)&(4,6) and other joining other points.

Thanks.

Edit: regarding "turn-around" .

The "overall line" consists of line segments each of whose slope is between -1 and +1. Each such "overall line" must be such that there does not exist a line x=const which cuts the "overall line" in more than one place.

Objective is to find minimum number of such "overall lines".

Comment: This is more of math problem than a programming problem to me. may need to ask in: http://math.stackexchange.com/?as=1 first.

Comment: Regarding the last example: is there really a line that connects (1,1) and (3,3) and (5,1) and doesn't turn around? If yes, what does "turn around mean"? If no (typo), please update the question to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider given set of points as oriented graph where points are vertices and there is an edge between two points iff they can be connected with a segment with slope between -1 and 1 . To deal with no turns arounds each edge would be oriented upwards (this will restrict moving downwards and thus getting turn arrouns). It is rather obvious that one line with your conditions corresponds to a path in this graph.

So having such graph your problem transforms into a famous one. The task is to cover an oriented acyclic graph with the minimal amount of ways. You can find a lot of material through the internet on this topic, for example take a look on this:

- [Minimum number of days required to solve a list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303800/minimum-number-of-days-required-to-solve-a-list-of-questions)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

**Edit:**
Initially I wrongly perceived turn-arround condition, I was considering `y=const` line. Actually edges must be oriented to the right (x1 < x2) or left (x1 > x2).

Comment: If I restrict my edges to be only upwards then in my second example above my answer would be 3, which is wrong. Also I understand that here path cover approach is applicable. How would you go about doing this via vertex cover?

Comment: How are you going to connect (1,1)-(3,3)-(5,1) with one line? As far as I see it has turn-arround in point (3,3).

Comment: Obviously in my answer I mean vertex cover, not the path one because you need to cover points with lines, don`t you?

Comment: Oh, I saw just now that the turn arround is when line `x=const` crosses it twice or more, not `y=const` one. So then just make all edges looking rightwise

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities that can be generated, and it is impossible to test all!
First thing that comes to my mind is the Genetic algorithm.

Not sure how to implement, but I think it could be handy.

Comment: Could you give any insight as to how to approach it with Genetic Algorithm. I believe that global minimum will take exponential time so I can use some approximate algorithm.