# DAG Minimum Path Cover in O(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, intervals

The following problem was asked in the recent [October 20-20 Hack on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/oct13/challenges/missile-defend) :

> Evil Nation A is angry and plans to launch N guided-missiles at the
>   peaceful Nation B in an attempt to wipe out all of Nation B’s people.
>   Nation A’s missile i will arrive in nation B at the time ti. Missile i
>   communicates with its headquarters by unique radio signals with a
>   frequency equal to fi. Can you help the peaceful Nation B survive by
>   building a defensive system that will stop the missiles dead in the
>   sky?
>
> **Defensive system:**
>
> The only way to defend Nation B from the attacking missile is by
>   counter attacking them with a hackerX missile. You have a lot of
>   hackerX missiles and each one of them has its own radio frequency. An
>   individual hackerX missile can destroy Evil Nation A’s attacking
>   missile if the radio frequency of both of the missiles match. Each
>   hackerX missile can be used an indefinite number of times. Its
>   invincible and doesn’t get destroyed in the collision.
>
> The good news is you can adjust the frequency of the hackerX missile
>   to match the evil missiles’ frequency. When changing the hackerX
>   missile’s initial frequency fA to the new defending frequency fB, you
>   will need |fB - fA| units of time to do.
>
> If two evil missles with same
>   frequency arrive at the same time, we can destroy them both with one
>   hackerX missile. You can set the frequency of a hackerX missile to any
>   value when its fired.
>
> What is the minimum number of hackerX missiles you must launch to keep
>   Nation B safe?
>
> **Input Format:** The first line contains a single integer N denoting the
>   number of missiles.  This is followed by N lines each containing two
>   integers ti and fi denoting the time & frequency of the ith missile.
>
> **Output Format:** A single integer denoting the minimum number of
>   hackerX’s you need to defend the nation.
>
> **Constraints:** 
>   1 <= N <= 100000
>
> 0 <= ti <= 100000
>
> 0 <= fi <= 100000
>
> t1 <= t2 <= … <= tN

The problem gets reduced to a Minimum Path Cover Problem which is to be solved in O(nlogn) time based on the constrainsts.
However the best solution to a Minimum Path Cover Problem is using the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm, that leads to the Maximal Matching Problem. The solution to which is O(n^2.5).
But the following solution by `icyrhyme9733` solves the problem in O(nlogn) :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<pair<int, int> > vp;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int t, f;
        cin >> t >> f;
        vp.push_back(make_pair(t + f, t - f));
    }
    sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());
    reverse(vp.begin(), vp.end());
    vector<int> last(vp.size(), numeric_limits<int>::max());
    for(int i = 0; i < vp.size(); ++i) {
        *lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), vp[i].second) = vp[i].second;
    }
    cout << lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), numeric_limits<int>::max()) - last.begin() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it solving a Minimum Path Cover Problem in O(nlogn) time ?  Or is there an optimization that I am missing ?

I found a similar problem on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508198/1016784). They have taken advantage of the fact that the graph is an Interval Graph. Even though being very similar, the same solution cannot be implemented, as the intervals are inverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem has been reduced to O(nlogn) using [Dilworth's Theoren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem)

A good tutorial on the above theorem can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-NW2fKIyLQ).

Answer (score 3):

Think about it this way:

#### Step 1: Characterize the case that 1 hacker-missile can cover 2 missiles

Given 2 missiles i and j such that t<sub>j</sub> >= t<sub>i</sub> (missiles are sorted by arrival time):

I can use the same hacker-missile to stop both i and j if the difference in frequency between them is less than or equal to the amount of time between their arrivals (because it takes 1 unit of time to change a frequency by 1).

More formally, the same hacker-missile can **cover** both i and j if:

> t<sub>j</sub> - t<sub>i</sub> >= |f<sub>i</sub> - f<sub>j</sub>|

Let's simplify:

#### Step 2: make an assumption

Let's for now assume that

> f<sub>i</sub> > f<sub>j</sub>

so we can get rid of the pesky absolute value symbols, yielding

> t<sub>j</sub> - t<sub>i</sub> >= f<sub>i</sub> - f<sub>j</sub>

We'll remove this assumption later.

Add f<sub>j</sub> to both sides

> t<sub>j</sub> - t<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>j</sub> >= f<sub>i</sub>

Add t<sub>i</sub> to both sides

> t<sub>j</sub>  + f<sub>j</sub> >= t<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>i</sub>

We know that we need at least 1 hacker-missile to cover the first arriving missile. The question is, how many other arriving missiles can it cover?

Well, a linear scan through the list would tell us that. We could just check to see if each subsequent value satisfies the inequality. But this would give us O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, and we can do better.

#### Step 3: Find an efficient solution given that assumption

First, let's sort the values by arrival time, with ties broken by t<sub>i</sub> + t<sub>j</sub>

This is akin to the line in the code:

```
sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());
```

(The author of the code reverses it afterwards to that `std::lower_bound` can be used, which we need because it will return an iterator to a value >= queried value, while `std::upper_bound` is strictly < queried value)

Since we know we need at least 1 hacker-missile to cover the first arriving missile, let's add our hacker-missile to a list of hacker-missiles that we are going to deploy, and let's mark them by the latest t<sub>i</sub>+f<sub>i</sub> they cover.

So, what do we do? As we iterate over the list of missiles from Nation A, we need to try to find a missile in Nation B's list of deployed hacker-missiles that can **cover** it.

This reduces to a binary search through our list of deployed missiles for one such that it can also cover the new missile. Recall from above that a missile can cover both i and j if

> t<sub>j</sub>  + f<sub>j</sub> >= t<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>i</sub>

Our hacker-missile in the list is associated with t<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>i</sub> and our new missile we need to cover is associated with t<sub>j</sub>  + f<sub>j</sub>

If we can find such a hacker-missile, replace its associated t<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>i</sub> with t<sub>j</sub>  + f<sub>j</sub>

The line of code that performs this operation is

```
*lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), vp[i].second) = vp[i].second;
```

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/?kw=lower_bound):

> lower_bound(first, last, val) Returns an iterator pointing to the
>   first element in the range [first,last) which does not compare less
>   than val.
>   In other words, it searches for a value greater than or equal to *val*

We'd like to not have to reverse the list and use `lower_bound`, but `upper_bound` strictly checks <, not <=. So we need to settle for reversing and using `lower_bound`
Note that the running time of `lower_bound` is logarithmic because it's essentially a binary search. If it fails, we insert a new hacker-missile to cover our new missile.

The author of the code gets around a strict insertion by just creating a list of hacker-missiles of size `n` and associating them with values of infinity:

```
vector<int> last(vp.size(), numeric_limits<int>::max());
```

When we go about **covering** the newest missile with the first hacker-missile that we can, we end up with a minimum set. Now we simply need to get the number of hacker-missiles we added to the list. If we went with strict insertion, we could call `vector.size()`, but since the author did not, he performs iterator subtraction to get the number of elements between the start and the first hacker-missile associated with infinity (or `vector.end()`):

```
lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), numeric_limits<int>::max()) - last.begin()
```

This post is a work in progress, and I'll update it as I figure things out.

Comment: _We know that we need at least 1 hacker-missile to cover the first arriving missile. The question is, how many other arriving missiles can it cover?
Well, a linear scan through the list would tell us that. We could just check to see if each subsequent value satisfies the inequality. But this would give us O(n2) time, and we can do better_
How Can we do this in O(n^2) complexity?
It may happen that there are three missiles `a`,`b` and `c` such that `b` can be destroyed after `a` or `c` can be destroyed after `a` by using a single missile. But destroying all three simultaneously is not possible.

Comment: _"First, let's sort the values by arrival time, with ties broken by ti + tj."_ - Isnt `sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());` sorting on the basis of `t_i+f_i` without breaking any ties ?

Comment: _"When we go about covering the newest missile with the first hacker-missile that we can, we end up with a minimum set."_ - Yes it seems to be working. But why is this greedy approach working ?

Comment: @Kyuubi: Yes, the author's sort is doing just that. My sort, however was on (t, t_i+fi), with ties broken by t_i+f_i. The greedy approach works in this case because of the sorting. I'm still trying to grok the author's exact approach better, but having trouble :(

Comment: So sorting `pair<>` using stl `sort()`, breaks ties using `pair.second` ? 
I understand what the author is doing. For a missile with interval `[i1,j1]` , he finds the next `IMMEDIATE` missile with interval `[i2,j2]` such that `i2 < i1` and `j2 < j1` , that is the first missile after [i1, j1] that can be killed with the same HackerX missile. The question now is, why can there not be a case such that the minimum number of HackerX missile used occurs when the next missile selection is `NON-IMMEDIATE`?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain the code in bits (whatever I could understand). IMO it is not solved as a maximal matching algorithm because it is interval based and it reduces much of the search space.

The code uses the following idea. Say there are following two missiles at times t1 and t2.

```
  (t1-f1)------t1------(t1+f1)  
(t2-f2)---t2---(t2+f2)
```

Now to use hackerX missile t2 for t1 also,
t1-t2 > f1-f2 (getting rid of mod for simplicity)
or
    t1-f1 > t2-f2

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  int t, f;
  cin >> t >> f;

  // pair's first part is max time till this hacker missile will stay valid.
  // pair's second part is t-f for comparison between consecutive missiles.
  vp.push_back(make_pair(t + f, t - f));
}

// sort on the basis of first part of pair.
sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());

reverse(vp.begin(), vp.end());

// vector containing initially very large numbers.
vector<int> last(vp.size(), numeric_limits<int>::max());

// start from the last time.
for(int i = 0; i < vp.size(); ++i) {

   // find the 1st entry that is not smaller than vp[i].second.
   // Make it equal to vp[i].second    
  *lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), vp[i].second) = vp[i].second;
}
// The number of new entries = number of hackerX missiles needed.
cout << lower_bound(last.begin(), last.end(), numeric_limits<int>::max()) - last.begin() << endl;
```

Comment: I understand what the code is doing. But whats surprising is that it is being solved in O(nlogn). Does this mean the `Minimum Path Cover` for an `Interval Graph` is always O(nlogn) or is this a special case that applies only to this situation ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about the general Minimum Path Cover with Interval Graph.